# sed find 01.00.* and replace with ${version}

Tags: sed

The command I am using is

```
sed -i "s/01.00.*/${version}/g" file.json
```

Result: `"${version}`

Expected `"${version}"`

Example:

```
"params": {
        "pipeline_branch":"master",
        "git_repo_url":"blah.git",
        "ARTIFACTORY_TAR_VERSION" : "01.00.00.26"
}
```

I want to be able to sed and replace 01.00.00.26 value ( or any 01.00.* which keeps changing, typically pom version ) with the value of "${version}" which is being retrieved passed through the shell.

I'm intending to run this on Linux through a Jenkins job. The `sed` command I use works (almost) perfectly, but removed the double quote in the last.

Comment: The only difference between your "Result" and the "Expected" is one quote? Do you want to use the literal string `${version}`, or whatever the value of the shell variable `version` is? And with quotes or not...?

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, you are right. Since I use * it truncates the quote " too. I would need a value of ${version} which would be some thing similar to 01.00.23.26

Comment: @roaima updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your sed command is that it matches too much.
Let's look at the pattern, then break it down:

```sed
/01.00.*/
```

```sed
 01       # exact match (so far, so good)
   .      # any character (too generous)
    00    # exact match
      .*  # the rest of the line
```

---

What we want to match is `01.00.` followed by any number of digits and dots:

```sed
/01\.00\.[.0-9]*/
```

Note that we use `\.` to match the dots, instead of `.` which matches any single character.

Answer (score -1):

The relevant line is this one

> ```
> "ARTIFACTORY_TAR_VERSION" : "01.00.00.26"
> ```

There are a couple of options: you could require `"ARTIFACTORY_TAR_VERSION"` to appear on the line, and then substitute something that looks like a version number, or you could be less cautious and just substitute anything that looks like a version number.

This option will replace anything that looks like a version number that contains `01.00.` and is followed by digits and dots:

```
sed -i "s/01\.00\.[0-9.]*/${version}/g" file.json
```

This one constrains the pattern to be bounded by double quotes (notice I switch mid-way through the RE from single-quoted to double-quoted protection against the shell interpreting the pattern):

```
sed -ri 's/(")[[:digit:].]*"/'"\1${version}\1/g" file.json
```

This final one also requires the pattern to match only on lines containing the word `VERSION` somewhere in them:

```
sed -ri '/VERSION/s/(")[[:digit:].]*"/'"\1${version}\1/g" file.json
```

Don't forget that for testing you don't necessarily need to modify the file *in situ*. You can omit the `-i` flag and inspect the output without changing the source file.

Comment: tried the first option which is sed -i "s/01\.00\.[0-9.]*/${version}/g" file.json 

And i get the error : `unexpected char: '\' `

Comment: @wizzy what OS are you running this on?

Comment: Also the option 2 which is `sed -i sed -ri 's/(")[[:digit:].]*"/01.00.00.246/g'`  doesn't work :(

Comment: Running it on Linux through a Jenkins job. 

The sed command i use works perfectly but removed the double quote in the last.

`sed -i "s/01.00.*/${version}/g" file.json `

Can i do one more sed to add a double quote in the last which is all i need

Comment: @wizzy they work perfectly for me at a (`bash`) shell prompt. Perhaps your Jenkins environment does something strange with backslashes? (I'm not familiar with Jenkins.)

Comment: @wizzy in a comment above here you mention an "option 2". Your code quoted in that comment does not match what I've provided (you've doubled up on the `sed -i` at the beginning, and you've omitted the necessary backreferences `\1` to the double quotes).

Answer (score -2):

sed -i "s/01.00.*\"/\${version}\"/g" file.json

Search the line till -- s/01.00.*\"/ 
Replace with  -- /${version}\"/

Comment: Why do you add the `i` there?